# Not working "Team Sync" for working with SVN pluggin

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse 2021.9

java 8

Success install plugin SVN. Success update from SVN repo my java project.

This pluggin installed:

[image]

Now I want to work with "Team Sync" perspective.

On Perspective `"Team synchronizing" , Tab "Synchronize" -> Click (arrow down) "Synchronize"`

[image]

Select **SVN**

[image]

Press **OK**

[image]

As you can see nothing to select.

Comment: You haven't specified the plug-in that you installed. Subclipse? Subversive?

Comment: @bahrep I was updated my post

Comment: There are two alternative Eclipse plugins for SVN: _Subversive_ and _Subclipse_. Install only one of them, not both (because you have installed both, two _SNV_ items shown in the list). Make also sure that the right connector is installed.

Comment: @howlger SVN interface: "javaHL 1.13". Stay only one SVN pluggin. But it not help.

Comment: What? JavaHL as connector for which plugin, Subversive or Subclipse? Which plugin did you keep? Why JavaHL and not SVNKit?

Comment: @howlger Installed only pluggin: Subclipse 4.3.3. I try SVNKit 1.10. But it not help.

Comment: According to the screenshots, you have both plugins installed, which is known to cause issues and mess the UI with similar items. Please improve your question. _"Click "Sync..."_ where?

Comment: @howlger I was updated my post

Comment: @howlger i found solution: 
Try right-clicking your project -> Team -> Share Project. The plugin will see the local SVN metadata and ask you if you'd like to reuse it (or drop it). Click Finish, and you should be all set.